# Issue with sendkeys in selenium is not entering the full value in TextFiled

Tags: java, python, selenium, testing, automation

We are facing an issue to enter the value in text area,the text is entered but its not full (i mean if they are 10lines its entering only four lines).

This particularly happens in IE browser.

I have a text which contains *,am replacing that * with some text according to my requirement.

Its a huge text may be of 10 lines.Am replacing the star(*) at every line and then storing it in a variable.Finally am using send keys to send this replaced value,Where am facing this problem only some value is entered.

When i used java script it work magically, full value got entered into textField.

But is there a better solution for this other than using java script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting your text string into chunks of let's say 1024 characters and call sendKeys() several times. To your test case behavior, it shouldn't make a difference whether you type one very long text or several short ones into the same text field.

Comment: Thats true...a simple common sense but great idea..thanks for answering